# Ag-grid button in cell that directs to new screen

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have added the "Edit" button in the grid of the table for every row. The data for the table is coming from the api with the following JSON response.

```
{ 
 Id: 1783
 total: 2
 trasfer: true
 Sizing: true
 name: "runner"
}
```

I am trying to implement when user clicks the edit button a new screen appears where one can edit the values of that row. So far I have implemented a button rendered component and alert when the button is click. How can I implement router to a new screen along with editable data of that particular row.

Demo: https://ag-grid2.zoltanhalasz.net/

**button-renderer.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="onClick($event)">{{label}}</button>
    `
})
export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp { 
    afterGuiAttached?(params?: import("ag-grid-community").IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
        return;
    }  
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        return;
    }
  public params;
  label: string;

  constructor(){}
  
  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.label = this.params.label || null;
}
  refresh(params: any): boolean {
    return false;
}

public onClick(event) {
    this.params.data[this.params.colDef.field] = event.checked;

    if (typeof this.params.context.componentParent.notifyCellUpdate === "function"){
        this.params.context.componentParent.CellUpdate(this.params);
    }
    
 }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
       columnDef = [   {
            headerName: 'Button',     field : 'changeSettings',     
            cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
            cellStyle: {'text-align': 'center'},
            cellRendererParams: {
              label: 'Open'
            }
          } ]

 CellUpdate(params){
      
        if (params.colDef.field === "changeSettings"){
            alert("Notified Button Clicked");
   
        }
    }
```

Comment: The link you've attached does so in a full page refresh. your equivalent would be to create a route that accepts the invoice number (id?) as parameter, then renders the edit component, which on init, fetches the invoice details. now, since you only have few fields to edit, I would suggest avoid routing and using a modal dialog instead to render the edit invoice component, that way, you can use the data listed on the table without creating a complex caching mechanism as you would need when using a separate route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component and navigate to it with input data.
There are many ways for transforming data between components.

[Read this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96)

In your sample demo you should define route with an id and navigate to it's component then call an `api` to fetch the data.

Also you can open a modal to show the data instead.
Example:

```
 CellUpdate(params){
      
        if (params.colDef.field === "changeSettings"){
          const modalRef = this.modalService.open(YourEditComponent);
          modalRef.componentInstance.data= params;   
        }
    }
```